# Invocar WCF que esta en otra Biblioteca de Clases desde JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, wcf

Hola tengo un problema al intentar llamar un Wcf que se encuentra en un Biblioteca de Clases, lo intento con JQuery haciendo las modificaciones necesarias, eh intentado algunas rutas relativas y absolutas en la URL del Ajax, lo estoy haciendo con un ejemplo sencillo anexo la imagen.
ya hice modificaciones en el WEb.Config
Quiero consumir del archivo js que esta dentro de la carpeta js, el WCF esta en la biblioteca de clases que esta abajo de llama Grafica.svc
Gracias de antemano por su ayuda.
[image: Imagen de proyecto]

Comment: Agrega mas información a tu pregunta  de como  piensas llamarlo  al servicio desde el lado cliente.

Comment: Tienes que cambiar tu  servicio a  formato Json para hacer eso. Esto te puede servir https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/132809/Calling-WCF-Services-using-jQuery

Comment: Gracias checare el formato Json

Comment: Me  avisas si te servicio el link  sino para explicarte después lo que tengas dudas. Justo hago un proyecto como el que buscas hacer con esa parte  de los servicios configurados para ser llamados como  WebApi.

Comment: Mira si tengo la funcionalidad cuando el WCF esta en la misma jerarquía de la pagína lo hace, cuando la mando a llamar desde otra Biblioteca de Clases ahí es cuando ya no hace nada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero que deberias validar es si esl servicio `WCF` responde correctamente, para ello toma la url y navegala desde el `browser`, deberias poder ver la pagina por defecto que el `.svc` expone, sino puede observar esa pagina entonces el servicio no esta escuchando request.

No se como estas realizando la invocacion desde el cliente por medio de ajax, pero si validas

[Calling WCF Services Using jQuery](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/calling-wcf-services-using-jquery/)

veras que utiliza

```
$.ajax({  
   type: "POST",  
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
   url: 'Service.svc/GetData',  
   success: function (data) { ...
```

basicamente como define la url, en este caso el sitio y el servicio estan en el mismo proyecto web, sino deberias definir la url completa, como ser:

```
http://<NombrePC o IP>:puerto/servicio.svc
```

ya que el cliente y el servicio estan en diferentes host

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta y ya verifique como me lo indicaste pero ahora mi sale este error, Failed to load http://localhost:55192/WCF_XXXXX.svc/WCF_PintaCombos: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:14331' is therefore not allowed access. Y no he podido resolverlo, el WCF ya contesta, pero no lo puedo consumirlo con Ajax Jquery, Saludos